# jquery/js : best way to have an image fading in and out? (recursion?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a better way than this, for two images positioned over each other where #state_2 is the top image.

```
function recursive_fade(){
    $('#top_img').delay(4000).fadeOut(400).delay(4000).fadeIn(400);
    recursive_fade();                
};

$(function(){
    recursive_fade(); 
});
```

When i dynatrace this, it seems to use fair bit of cpu...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use continuation-style here: let the fx system call the `recursive_fade` when the last animation has finished:

```
function recursive_fade(){
    $('#top_img')
         .delay(4000)
         .fadeOut(400)
         .delay(4000)
         .fadeIn(400, recursive_fade );
};
```

EDIT 2 - meanwhile, it seems (long liveth the [jQuery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/continuation-style-programming-are-there-constraints-on-the-fx-callbacks)) that the Effects are implemented using a queue and the setTimeout function - making EDIT 1 obsolete.

<strike>EDIT - since I have no idea if jQuery allows this recursion (I didn't find convincing proof), I think it's best to combine the "Timeout" suggestions with the continuation technique like so:</strike>

```
function recursive_fade(){
    $('#top_img')
         .delay(4000)
         .fadeOut(400)
         .delay(4000)
         .fadeIn(400, function() { setTimeout( recursive_fade, 0 ); } );
};
```

This offers the guarantee that stack won't blow up, yet avoids the need to calculate the timeout interval.

Comment: So will making the recursive function a callback save CPU? I thought all jquery animations were syncrous?

Comment: The callback is, as you say, going to be called from a timer.  It's not going to call itself, rather _schedule_ a call at the moment the effects are done.  And, as I mentioned indirectly, the jQuery effects are _asynchronous_.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it recursively, I would use a setTimeout so it doesnt totally lock up the browser.

```
function recursive_fade(){
    $('#top_img').delay(4000).fadeOut(400).delay(4000).fadeIn(400);
    setTimeout(function(){recursive_fade(); },8800);               
};

$(function(){
   recursive_fade();
});
```

Comment: and on every change in the fx timings, you need  to update the timeout argument.

Comment: ... Loktar - I've been asking around.  There is no risk to lock up the browser since the effects functions already use timers.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `setInterval()`. Info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval).

Something like this:

```
function fadeShow() {
    $('#top_img').delay(4000).fadeOut(400).delay(4000).fadeIn(400);
}
$(function() {
    setInterval(fadeShow, 8800);
}
```

Comment: This way you have e tight coupling between the arguments of the whole animation sequence, and your timeout interval.  I would rather use `setTimeout` in the `callback` of the `fadeIn`.